# Creating a getLast method for Linked Lists

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I'm trying to hand code a getLast method in Java. I know what I have to do, I'm just having trouble coding it. What I need to do is traverse the linked list until p.link points to null, then I can add to the end of the list. Here's what I have so far:

```
class MyLinkedList 
{
   private class Node           
   {
      private Node link;
      private int x;
   }
   //----------------------------------
   private Node first = null;    
   //----------------------------------
   public void addFirst(int d)
   {
      Node newNode = new Node(); 
      newNode.x = d;            
      newNode.link = first;      
      first = newNode;           
   } 

   public void addLast(int q)
   {
      Node newNode = new Node();
      newNode.x = q;
      newNode.link = null;  //points to null because nothing should follow it
   //----------------------------------
   public void traverse()
   {
      Node p = first;
      while (p != null)            
      {
         System.out.println(p.x);  
         p = p.link;               
      }
   }
}
//==============================================
class C15h1  
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      MyLinkedList list = new MyLinkedList();
      list.addLast(4);
      list.addLast(5);
     list.addLast(6);
      list.addFirst(1);
      list.addFirst(2);
      list.addFirst(3);
      System.out.println("Numbers on list");
      list.traverse();
   }
}
```

Comment: This is it: `until p.link points to null,` So how could you model that statement with a `while` (or other) loop?

Comment: Iterate all the node from the head till you find `node.link` is equals to `null`.

Comment: what is the int x field in your private class Node?

Comment: also you may want to change your "link" field to some more intuitive names such as "next" or "nextNode", because "link" can point to either direction (next or prev). It's just confusing.

Comment: in addLast where are you pointing your new node ? its just creating and making its link to null but no where its related to your linked list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would keep track of the last node:

```
class MyLinkedList 
{
   private class Node           
   {
        private Node link;
        private int x;
   }
    //----------------------------------
    private Node first = null;    
    private Node last = null;    
    //----------------------------------

    public void addFirst(int d)
    {
        Node newNode = new Node(); 
        newNode.x = d;            
        newNode.link = first;      
        first = newNode;
        if(last == null)
            last = newNode;           
    } 

    public void addLast(int q)
    {
        Node newNode = new Node();
        newNode.x = q;
        newNode.link = null;  //points to null because nothing should follow it
        if(last != null)
            last.link = newNode;
        last = newNode;
        if(first == null) // This is the first node
            first = newNode;
    }

    //----------------------------------
    public void traverse()
    {
        Node p = first;
        while (p != null)            
        {
            System.out.println(p.x);  
            p = p.link;               
        }
    }

    public int getLast()
    {
        if(last != null)
            return last.q;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this may be what you wanted?

```
public Node getLast()
{
    Node lastNode = first;
    Node next = first.link;

    while (next != null)
    { 
         lastNode = next;
         next = next.link; 
    }

    return lastNode;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your current code is in the `traverse()` method. It loops until `p == null`  which means that you stop when `p` "fell" out of the list. What you want is to stop one step before that such `p` is pointing at the very last item of the list. To do that you simply need to change the condition from `while (p != null)` to `while (p.link != null)`.

Here's how `addLast()` should look like:

```
public void addLast(int q)
{
   Node newNode = new Node();
   newNode.x = q;
   newNode.link = null;  //points to null because nothing should follow it

   Node p = first;
   while (p.link != null) {
      p = p.link;               
   }
   p.link = newNode;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

iterate till you get last node using while loop and once foinds last node return it..

```
 public Node getLast(){
    Node p = first;
          while (p.link != null)            
          { 
             p = p.link;               
          }
    return p;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through your list till the end. (Just like as you mentioned. 'until p.link points to null,')

You could do something like this:

```
public void addLast(int q) {
    Node newNode = new Node();
    newNode.x = q;
    newNode.link = null;
    if (first == null) {
        first = newNode;
    } else {
        Node lastNode = first;
        while (lastNode != null && lastNode.link != null) {
            lastNode = lastNode.link;
        }
        lastNode.link = newNode;
    }
}
```